# Is it ok to use text area for multiple subjects?

Tags: forms, input-fields, text

When user is answering question with radio buttons that opens new more specific questions. Is it bad idea to wrap those questions in one text area?

In my case user want might add multiple "compensations" so if used text fields there should be feature that enables adding multiple different "compensations". With text area there's no need for that feature because user can add all the information in one field.

I think text fields would be more clear in many case but in this one it might be better to use text area, or what you think?

[image: Screenshot from layout]

Comment: Well, why not just have one single text area that does the whole form? Answer that, and you will have your answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I forgot explain that text fields/area shows up when user clicks yes. Radio button question would be mandatory and after user answers yes text fields/area shows up. If you meant to use only text area that should be optional? And in that case user could skip that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> user want might add multiple "compensations"

Assuming the field(s) are optional. In that case, better to have one Textarea instead of multiple text fields.

**Reason:**

People usually don't like too many question fields for a single reason :). I am also thinking you might want to rename the label to something generic like "Please explain" instead of "What, where, and when".

Comment: Thanks for answer! "Please explain" might be too open but good idea to rethink label.